# How to show element name in portuguese using elements package?

Tags: babel, languages, chemistry

I have to do a big table using the chemical elements names in portuguese. I'm using the `elements` package to do that, but don't works. Below following a few examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{elements}
\begin{document}
    Result: \elementname{Na} \par
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: English]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{elements}
\begin{document}
    Result: \elementname{Na} \par
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: German]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{elements}
\begin{document}
    Result: \elementname{Na} \par
    Expected: Sódio
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elements seems to suggest the package only speaks English, French, German and Spanish. So someone would have to teach it Portuguese for this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As moewe said there's no translation for Portuguese available. However it's easy to provide one. I took the French as template, copied the list of names from [this site](https://www.areaseg.com/sinais/elementos.html) (I'm not a chemist, so I don't know how correct is that) and used some regex replacements for accents. Save this file as `elements_names_portuges.def` (not `portuguese`) somewhere TeX can find it:

```latex
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
% the ELEMENTS package
% 
%   retrieve different properties of chemical elements
% 
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Clemens Niederberger
% Web:    https://github.com/cgnieder/elements/
% E-Mail: contact@mychemistry.eu
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Copyright 2015--2018 Clemens Niederberger
% 
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
% 
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clemens Niederberger.
% 
% Portuguese translation added by Phelype Oleinik
%   from https://www.areaseg.com/sinais/elementos.html
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareAtomName[Hidrogenio]{001}{Hidrog\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Helio]{002}{H\'elio}
\DeclareAtomName[Litio]{003}{L{\'\i}tio}
\DeclareAtomName[Berilio]{004}{Ber{\'\i}lio}
\DeclareAtomName{005}{Boro}
\DeclareAtomName{006}{Carbono}
\DeclareAtomName[Nitrogenio]{007}{Nitrog\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Oxigenio]{008}{Oxig\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Fluor]{009}{Fl\'uor}
\DeclareAtomName[Neonio]{010}{Ne\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Sodio]{011}{S\'odio}
\DeclareAtomName[Magnesio]{012}{Magn\'esio}
\DeclareAtomName[Aluminio]{013}{Alum{\'\i}nio}
\DeclareAtomName[Silicio]{014}{Sil{\'\i}cio}
\DeclareAtomName[Fosforo]{015}{F\'osforo}
\DeclareAtomName{016}{Enxofre}
\DeclareAtomName{017}{Cloro}
\DeclareAtomName[Argonio]{018}{Arg\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Potassio]{019}{Pot\'assio}
\DeclareAtomName[Calcio]{020}{C\'alcio}
\DeclareAtomName[Escandio]{021}{Esc\^andio}
\DeclareAtomName[Titanio]{022}{Tit\^anio}
\DeclareAtomName[Vanadio]{023}{Van\'adio}
\DeclareAtomName{024}{Cromo}
\DeclareAtomName[Manganes]{025}{Mangan\^es}
\DeclareAtomName{026}{Ferro}
\DeclareAtomName{027}{Cobalto}
\DeclareAtomName[Niquel]{028}{N{\'\i}quel}
\DeclareAtomName{029}{Cobre}
\DeclareAtomName{030}{Zinco}
\DeclareAtomName[Galio]{031}{G\'alio}
\DeclareAtomName[Germanio]{032}{Germ\^anio}
\DeclareAtomName[Arsenio]{033}{Ars\'enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Selenio]{034}{Sel\'enio}
\DeclareAtomName{035}{Bromo}
\DeclareAtomName[Criptonio]{036}{Cript\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Rubidio]{037}{Rub{\'\i}dio}
\DeclareAtomName[Estroncio]{038}{Estr\^oncio}
\DeclareAtomName[Itrio]{039}{\'Itrio}
\DeclareAtomName[Zirconio]{040}{Zirc\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Niobio]{041}{Ni\'obio}
\DeclareAtomName[Molibdenio]{042}{Molibd\'enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Tecnecio]{043}{Tecn\'ecio}
\DeclareAtomName[Rutenio]{044}{Rut\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Rodio]{045}{R\'odio}
\DeclareAtomName[Paladio]{046}{Pal\'adio}
\DeclareAtomName{047}{Prata}
\DeclareAtomName[Cadmio]{048}{C\'admio}
\DeclareAtomName[Indio]{049}{\'Indio}
\DeclareAtomName{050}{Estanho}
\DeclareAtomName[Antimonio]{051}{Antim\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Telurio]{052}{Tel\'urio}
\DeclareAtomName{053}{Iodo}
\DeclareAtomName[Xenonio]{054}{Xen\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Cesio]{055}{C\'esio}
\DeclareAtomName[Bario]{056}{B\'ario}
\DeclareAtomName[Lantanio]{057}{Lant\^anio}
\DeclareAtomName[Cerio]{058}{C\'erio}
\DeclareAtomName[Praseodimio]{059}{Praseod{\'\i}mio}
\DeclareAtomName[Neodimio]{060}{Neod{\'\i}mio}
\DeclareAtomName[Promecio]{061}{Prom\'ecio}
\DeclareAtomName[Samario]{062}{Sam\'ario}
\DeclareAtomName[Europio]{063}{Eur\'opio}
\DeclareAtomName[Gadolinio]{064}{Gadol{\'\i}nio}
\DeclareAtomName[Terbio]{065}{T\'erbio}
\DeclareAtomName[Disprosio]{066}{Dispr\'osio}
\DeclareAtomName[Holmio]{067}{H\'olmio}
\DeclareAtomName[Erbio]{068}{\'Erbio}
\DeclareAtomName[Tulio]{069}{T\'ulio}
\DeclareAtomName[Iterbio]{070}{It\'erbio}
\DeclareAtomName[Lutecio]{071}{Lut\'ecio}
\DeclareAtomName[Hafnio]{072}{H\'afnio}
\DeclareAtomName[Tantalo]{073}{T\^antalo}
\DeclareAtomName[Tungstenio]{074}{Tungst\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Renio]{075}{R\^enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Osmio]{076}{\'Osmio}
\DeclareAtomName[Iridio]{077}{Ir{\'\i}dio}
\DeclareAtomName{078}{Platina}
\DeclareAtomName{079}{Ouro}
\DeclareAtomName[Mercurio]{080}{Merc\'urio}
\DeclareAtomName[Talio]{081}{T\'alio}
\DeclareAtomName{082}{Chumbo}
\DeclareAtomName{083}{Bismuto}
\DeclareAtomName[Polonio]{084}{Pol\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Astatinio]{085}{Astat{\'\i}nio}
\DeclareAtomName[Radonio]{086}{Rad\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Francio]{087}{Fr\^ancio}
\DeclareAtomName[Radio]{088}{R\'adio}
\DeclareAtomName[Actinio]{089}{Act{\'\i}nio}
\DeclareAtomName[Torio]{090}{T\'orio}
\DeclareAtomName[Protactinio]{091}{Protact{\'\i}nio}
\DeclareAtomName[Uranio]{092}{Ur\^anio}
\DeclareAtomName[Netunio]{093}{Net\'unio}
\DeclareAtomName[Plutonio]{094}{Plut\^onio}
\DeclareAtomName[Americio]{095}{Amer{\'\i}cio}
\DeclareAtomName[Curio]{096}{C\'urio}
\DeclareAtomName[Berquelio]{097}{Berqu\'elio}
\DeclareAtomName[Californio]{098}{Calif\'ornio}
\DeclareAtomName[Einstenio]{099}{Einst\'enio}
\DeclareAtomName[Fermio]{100}{F\'ermio}
\DeclareAtomName[Mendelevio]{101}{Mendel\'evio}
\DeclareAtomName[Nobelio]{102}{Nob\'elio}
\DeclareAtomName[Laurencio]{103}{Laur\^encio}
\DeclareAtomName[Rutherfordio]{104}{Rutherf\'ordio}
\DeclareAtomName[Dubnio]{105}{D\'ubnio}
\DeclareAtomName[Seaborgio]{106}{Seab\'orgio}
\DeclareAtomName[Bohrio]{107}{B\'ohrio}
\DeclareAtomName[Hassio]{108}{H\'assio}
\DeclareAtomName[Meitnerio]{109}{Meitn\'erio}
\DeclareAtomName{110}{Darmstadtio}
\DeclareAtomName[Unununio]{111}{Unun\'unio}
\DeclareAtomName[Unumbio]{112}{Un\'umbio}

\endinput
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @GRSousaJr Good to know :-) If you happen to find any wrong name in that list feel free to correct it.

Comment: I'll search for any occurrence. I'm intent to update and complete the list up until 118-element. Thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik do you mind if I add this to `elements`?

Comment: @clemens Of course not, feel free to use it :-)

Comment: @clemens The elements names in this list are in European Portuguese. To Brazilian Portuguese there are a couple of differences, almost of them about accentuation. Did you would like also include these variations?

Comment: @GRSousaJr Ooh, I completely overlooked that. I noticed the ones ending with `enio`: Arsênio, Selênio, Molibdênio, and Einstênio (all with acute accent in the answer above). Are there more?

Comment: @GRSousaJr If you have some time, could you please leave a comment at https://github.com/cgnieder/elements/issues/5 about the European and Brazilian difference? I could spot the obvious cases, but I'm not that familiar with chemistry to know the proper spelling of all the elements. Thanks!

Comment: Besides those cases notice by you, there are: 101 Md Mendelévio, 110 Ds Darmstádio, 111 Rg Roentgênio, 112 Cn Copernício, 113 Nh Nihônio, 114 Fl Fleróvio, 115 Mc Moscóvio, 116 Lv Livermório, 117 Ts Tennesso, 118 Og Oganessônio (I included the last ones discovered elements).

Comment: @GRSousaJr please feel free to send me a file `elements_names_brazil.def` with the corresponding changes, either as pull request or per email. Please use https://github.com/cgnieder/elements/blob/master/elements_names_portuges.def as a start (I added element names up to element 118)

Comment: @GRSousaJr I would like to add it to `elements` before I upload the new version to CTAN :)